# Check Username Availability in ASP.Net using AJAX DOJO Toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, dojo

I'm currently trying to develop a small demo using DOJO Toolkit to write an AJAX in ASP.NET to check for username availability.

This is my RegisterPage.aspx:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/dojo/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad:true, isDebug:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require('dojo.parser');
        dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.NumberSpinner");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
        dojo.require("dojox.validate");
        dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
        dojo.require("dojox.validate.web");
        dojo.require("dojox.form.PasswordValidator");
        // To use AJAX
        dojo.require("dojo._base.xhr");
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // When the DOM is ready....
        dojo.ready(function () {
            // Local var representing the node to be updated
            var availabilityNode = dojo.byId("availabilityNode");
            var usernameNode = dojo.byId("accountName");
            // Connect button
            dojo.connect(usernameNode, "onkeyup", function () {
                // Get the value
                var value = dojo.trim(usernameNode.value.toLowerCase());
                // If there's code...
                if (value != "") {
                    // Using dojo.xhrGet, as very little information is being sent
                    dojo.xhrPost({
                        // The URL of the request
                        url: "./RegisterPage.aspx/checkUserName",
                        // Allow only 2 seconds for username check
                        timeout: 2000,
                        // Send the username to check base on an INPUT node's value
                        content: {
                            userName: value
                        },
                        handleAs: "text",
                        
                        // The success callback with result from server
                        load: function (result, args) {
                            if (result == "false") {
                                availabilityNode.style.color = "green";
                                availabilityNode.innerHTML = "Username available!";
                            } else {
                                availabilityNode.style.color = "red";
                                availabilityNode.innerHTML = "Username taken!  Please try another.";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    availabilityNode.innerHTML = "";
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<body class="tundra">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="jscripts/AjaxDojoPatch.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">
       if (this.validate()){
        return confirm("Form is valid, press OK to submit");
       }else{
        alert('Form contains invalid data.  Please correct first');
        return false;
       }
       return true;
        </script>

        <h1>DEMO REGISTER PAGE</h1>
        <table width="80%">
            <tr>
                <td>Account Name*:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="accountName" name="accountName" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true"
                        missingMessage="Ooops!  You forgot your account name!" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <!-- <asp:Button ID="btnCheckExist" runat="server" dojoType="dijit.form.Button"
                                type="button" CausesValidation="false" label="Check Exist" Text="Check Exist" /> -->
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_check" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <span id="availabilityNode"></span>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password*:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="pwd1" TextMode="Password" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                        required="true" type="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>E-mail*:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="email" required="true" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" runat="server"
                        data-dojo-props="validator:dojox.validate.isEmailAddress, invalidMessage:'This is not a valid email!'"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="birthDate" runat="server" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                        value="7/5/1983"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button"
                        type="submit" runat="server" label="Submit" Text="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading... please wait
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </form>
</body>
```

And my Code Behind (RegisterPage.aspx.cs):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string checkUserName(string userName)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connMain"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection currentConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        // Create the command that will contain the SQL statement.
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE accountName = '" + userName + "'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = currentConnection;

        currentConnection.Open();

        if (userName.Length == 0)
        {
            returnValue = "false";
        }
        else
        {
            returnValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return returnValue;
    }
    finally
    {
        currentConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

When i tried to type in Username Textbox, it's always get the same result: "Username taken!  Please try another."
Please help me fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend that **when you get this working**, you head over to [CodeReview.SE] and get some feedback on what can be done better in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) your connection and command objects. They implement [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which means they have resources to free, and you don't free them.

---

Second, use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx). You are *very* open to SQL injection right now.

---

Third, there's no reason to set the `CommandType`. It [defaults to `Text`](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=SqlCommand.CommandType).

---

The problem appears to be in your codebehind logic. The problem is that you check `userName.Length`, but you never change `userName` to anything except whatever the user input. So it's *always* going to have a length greater than 0 so long as the user didn't input a blank name. Most specifically, this section:

> ```
>     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
>     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE accountName = '" + userName + "'";
>     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
>     cmd.Connection = currentConnection;
>
>     currentConnection.Open();
>
>     if (userName.Length == 0)
>     {
>         returnValue = "false";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         returnValue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
>     }
>
>     return returnValue;
> ```

Doing the following should fix your issue:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE accountName = @Username";
    cmd.Connection = currentConnection;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            returnValue = "false";
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Read();
            returnValue = reader["accountName"];
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

This should show you how to make all the changes I mentioned, and fix your issue.